# Configure Resident Instances in Local Dev Server

Tags: google-app-engine

It takes about 30 seconds for my app to warm up and I often find that if I leave my local server running for a while without any activities, it becomes very slow for the new requests.

I tried to do a repeating CURL to the warm up endpoint, but somehow it doesn't work as well I expected.

How can I configure my local app server to have a min number of resident instances, like in production ?

Comment: just run few instances, i mean run this command few times, for different ports (balanced by nginx for example). or write a bash/bat script to run few instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your local dev environment is nothing more than a webserver with a few tweaks to emulate the Google infrastructure. The concept of resident instances is not valid as you dont have a pool of VMs being started and stopped like you would have on your production environment.

If your app is turning slow after some idle time the most likely reasons are:

1) Your local OS is stripping down resources and allocating them somewhere else.

2) Your app is running some maintainance processes (garbage collection?) and destroying whatever memory dependent objects you are building during warmup.

Without any  information on your app it's very hard to tell but both issues are solved by having a minimum level of activty on your app, consider having some cron (not GAE's as it doesnt work on dev) do a ping every X minutes, accesing some key resources so that your app remains active.

On a side note: having a 30 sec warmup can have a really bad impact on user experience on prod as your instances will be shut down an restarted constantly. You can diminish the blow by using resident instances but you should really consider optimizing that startup time in order to get the most out of the GAE's infrastructure.

Comment: That's kind of what I thought and agree that warm up time is a big problem we need to tackle...